# can someone identify this lego character for me?

Tags: minifigure-identification

I have a mini figure that I can't find on the web or any where else (I also don't have any instructions for it). Not sure where it came from but I found it in a pile of lego at home that I collected years ago.

[image]
[image]

Can someone please tell me what number these 'pieces' are or tell me what lego set this came from. That would be great!

Answer (score 11):

this appears to be
[Robot Devastator 4 - Red Eyes](http://brickset.com/minifigs/exf015/Robot-Devastator-4-Red-Eyes)
[image]

from the following sets

[8101-1:Claw Crusher](http://brickset.com/sets/8101-1/Claw-Crusher)
or
[8107: Fight for the Golden Tower](http://brickset.com/sets/8107-1/Fight-for-the-Golden-Tower)
or
[8112: Arachnoid Stalker](http://brickset.com/sets/8112-1/Arachnoid-Stalker) or [8115: Dark Panther](http://brickset.com/sets/8115-1/Dark-Panther)

Partlist for Devastator

[Bricklink part list](http://www.bricklink.com/catalogItemInv.asp?M=exf015)

Answer (score 2):

That figure came in quite a few [Exoforce](http://brickset.com/minifigs/category-Exo-Force) sets a few years ago in both silver and bronze. As far as which sets, I don't recall, but I hoped it helped.

Answer (score 0):

That looks like "[Robot Devastator 4](http://www.brickowl.com/catalog/lego-robot-devastator-exo-force-minifigure)", which came in [red-eyed](http://brickset.com/minifigs/exf015/Robot-Devastator-4-Red-Eyes) and [regular](http://brickset.com/minifigs/exf018/Robot-Devastator-4) versions.